# increment '00'+n in for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm trying to make a for loop with numbers given by user **($start and $limit)**, but I want to be able to write '0001' as `$start` and '1000' as `$limit` and print each one of numbers. The problem is, only the first number is printed as '000..' and after increment, those zeros disappear. This is my code:

```
 $start = 0001;
 $limit = 1000;

 for ($i=$start; $i <= $limit; $i++) {
   echo $i.'<br>';
 }
```

outputs:

```
001
2
3
...
1000
```

Is there any way to make it as:

```
0001
0002
...
1000
```

Comment: Use [`printf('%04d')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Comment: yes! that's the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  $start = 1;
  $limit = 1000;

   for ($i=$start; $i <= $limit; $i++) {
      printf("%04d<br>",$i);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you bro I just found the same answer IT WORKS!